How to run a list through a function
I am having a hard time figuring out how I can run this list of Fahrenheit degrees to convert into Celsius.
# List of half-hourly temperature values (in degrees Fahrenheit) for one week
tempData =  [19, 21, 21, 21, 23, 23, 23, 21, 19, 21, 19, 21, 23, 27, 27, 28, 30, 30]

# This function is to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius
def fahrToCelsius(tempFahrenheit):
  #This is the formula to convert the Fahrenheit input to Celsius.
  convertedTemp = ((tempFahrenheit - 32)/ 1.8)
  #This returns the results of the converted temperature.
  return convertedTemp

Error I'm receiving is: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'.
I have tried assigning the tempFahrenheit = tempData but I'm still getting the error message.

You cannot use fahrToCelsius() to handle the list directly because the input of the function is number instead of a list. You need to handle each element inside the list.
Here's one solution:
# List of half-hourly temperature values (in degrees Fahrenheit) for one week
tempData = [19, 21, 21, 21, 23, 23, 23, 21, 19, 21, 19, 21, 23, 27, 27, 28, 30, 30]

# This function is to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius
def fahrToCelsius(tempFahrenheit):
    # This is the formula to convert the Fahrenheit input to Celsius.
    convertedTemp = (tempFahrenheit - 32) / 1.8
    # This returns the results of the converted temperature.
    return convertedTemp

# Convert each temperature value in tempData to Celsius
celsiusData = [fahrToCelsius(temp) for temp in tempData]


Thank you so much! This was a huge help!

Try map:
convertedData = list(map(lambda x: fahrToCelsius(x), tempData))

or more simple:
convertedData = list(map(lambda x: ((x - 32) / 1.8), tempData))


You don't even need the lambda.

You have to iterate over the elements of your list.
The way you write your conversion function will depend to a certain extent on what you want to do with the converted values. Do you just want to print them, create a new list, replace the values in situ?
You may find a generator more flexible.
For example:
tempData = [19, 21, 21, 21, 23, 23, 23, 21, 19, 21, 19, 21, 23, 27, 27, 28, 30, 30]

def fahrenheitToCelsius(temps):
    for f in temps: # iterate over the list
        yield (f - 32) / 1.8

Then let's say you just want to print the converted values then:
for c in fahrenheitToCelsius(tempData):
    print(f"{c:.1f}C")

...or if you want a new list then:
cData = list(fahrenheitToCelsius(tempData))


tempData = [19,21,21,21,23,23,23,21,19,21,19,21,23,27,27,28,30, 30]
#this is your given list
#creating a list to store new data of temperature
f_data=[]
#now looping data using for loop
for c_temp in tempData:  #it will take one element at a time from tempData
    f_temp = (c_temp * 9/5) + 32
#now using formula for conversion from `C to `F 
#adding modified data to f_data   
f_data.append(f_temp)

print(f_data) #will print whole data in form of list


A list comprehension would be a good idea here. f_data = [(c_temp * 9/5) + 32 for c_temp in tempData]

it would be more instructive to the original question to keep a conversion function and call it within the loop.  Also, you changed the direction of the conversion with no explanation.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
